# Changing image based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

This is my html file. I am trying to display an image in the div section after the dropdown selection changes. The source of the image is in the XML file. It gives an error stating Cannot set property 'src' of null. Please help.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>
            </title>
            </head>
    <body>

    <img id="change" src="ecomm.jpg" onload="loadXMLDoc()"/>
      <div id="imagechange" >

          </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**Script**

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            myFunction(xmlhttp);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "bf.xml", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml) {
    var i;
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;

    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("food");

    var str ="<select id='image' onchange='changeFunc(this.value);'>";
    str+= "<option value='select image'> Select Image </image>";

    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        str +='<option value=' + x[i].getElementsByTagName("source")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '>' + x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</option>'; 
    }

    str +='</select>';
    document.write(str);

}

function changeFunc(val) {
    document.getElementById('change').src = val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `document.write(str);`
This method replaces your whole document with `str` thus removing `'change'`.

You want to append the  element using `document.getElementById('change').appendChild(str)`.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Comment: I tried using that but then it throws the below error.

Comment: 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: So append it to a node. As it turns out, you have a nice `<div id="imagechange" >` that is not being used at all. Put your `<select>` in there. I have updated my answer